# Creating a key value message in Smalltalk/Pharo that take blocks as argument

Tags: error-handling, promise, smalltalk, pharo

I have a scenario where a class holds two instance variables that are mutually exclusive. That is only one can be instantiated at a time. To be precise, I have a Promise class (trying to add promises to Pharo) and it holds promiseError and promiseValue instance variables. I then want to implement the method "then: catch:". 
This method should work as follows:

```
promiseObject := [10/0] promiseValue.
promiseObject then : [ : result | Transcript crShow : result ]
catch : [ : failure | Transcript crShow : failure ] .
```

I got an idea on how to implement methods that take a block as an argument from [method that accepts a block and the block accepts an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889234/method-that-accepts-a-block-and-the-block-accepts-an-argument).
My attempt below will obviously not work but I have no idea on how to make it work.

```
   then:aBlock catch: anotherBlock
    |segment|
    promiseValue ifNil: [ segment := promiseError  ] ifNotNil:  [ segment := promiseValue ].
    promiseValue ifNil: [ segment := promiseValue  ] ifNotNil:  [ segment := promiseError ].
    aBlock value:segment.
    anotherBlock value: segment
```

This should work analogously to a try-catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
then: aBlock catch: anotherBlock
  promiseError notNil ifTrue: [^anotherBlock value: promiseError].
  ^aBlock value: promiseValue
```

Note that the code does not rely on `promiseValue` being `nil` or not because `nil` could be a valid answer of the `promise`. However, if there is some `promiseError`, we know the `promise` failed, and succeeded otherwise.

Of course, here I'm assuming that this message will get sent once the `promise` has been successfully or unsuccessfully finished. If this is not the case, then the code should be waiting on the `promise` semaphore.

Comment: I have a related question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086700/pharo-subscriptoutofbounds5-error